# Pending tx's with full information

Tags: parity, pending-transactions

Is it possible to subscribe to pending transactions with Parity and receive full information about it in 1 request? Now i receive hashes first, and than i make requests to get info about this hashes. I want to do it in 1 request.

Thank you.